# Was Tokugawa Ieyasu a fake?

Tags: fuse

In *Fusé: Memoirs of a Huntress*, when we see Tokugawa Ieyasu, he is chanting to a scroll, praying to "keep impostors out"

When Shino reaches him, Tokugawa pulls the sword out of the scroll before his head disappears into his robes and pops back out again, with his face looking like that of the father of the woman who gave birth to the first Fusé as depicted in the Kabuki Play.

During the fight, Tokugawa talks about how he would kill Shino, the last Fusé, to correct the mistake he made for allowing his daughter to give birth to them (the Fusé, not Shino). After the fight, his head disappears again to pop back out with Tokugawa's original face.

Was Tokugawa Ieyasu a fake, or did this change have anything to do with the sword he was holding?